# How to loop through common id values in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I recently started working on XSLT. I have a requirement of grouping node values based on id field. However id field could be a duplicate value. For example, lets say below is the XML structure.

```html
<ProductResults> 
<ProductResult>                     
  <ProductId>1000</ProductId>
  <Location>Bangalore</Location>
  <ModuleNumber>02</ModuleNumber>
                <StoreId>1234<StoreId>    
</ProductResult>
<ProductResult>      
  <ProductId>2000</ProductId>
  <ModuleNumber>03</ModuleNumber>
  <Location>Bangalore</Location>
                <StoreId>1234<StoreId>  
</ProductResult>
<ProductResult> 
  <ProductId>1000</ProductId>
  <ModuleNumber>01</ModuleNumber>
  <Location>Mumbai</Location>
                <StoreId>1234<StoreId> 
</ProductResult>
<ProductResult>  
  <ProductId>4000</ProductId>
  <ModuleNumber>02</ModuleNumber>
  <Location>Kolkata</Location>
                <StoreId>1234<StoreId> 
</ProductResult>
<ProductResult>  
  <ProductId>1000</ProductId>
  <ModuleNumber>03</ModuleNumber>
  <Location>Chennai</Location>
                <StoreId>1234<StoreId> 
</ProductResult>
</ProductResults>
```

If you notice, the ProductId 1000 is repeating thrice. I am supposed to write XSLT to produce below output.

```js
{
  "StoreId": "1234",
  "Locations": [
    {
      "ProductId": "1000",
      "Locations": [
        {
          "Location": "Bangalore",
          "ModuleNumber": "02"
        },
        {
          "Location": "Mumbai",
          "ModuleNumber": "01"
        },
        {
          "Location": "Chennai",
          "ModuleNumber": "03"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "2000",
      "Locations": [
        {
          "Location": "Bangalore",
          "ModuleNumber": "03"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "4000",
      "Locations": [
        {
          "Location": "Kolkata",
          "ModuleNumber": "02"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Since the ProductId field is repeating, I cannot use foreach loop directly which creates extra code block for same ProductId . Any suggestions on this?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a *grouping* question - do a search. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
            version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:variable name="uniqueProducts" 
              select="count(//ProductId[not(. = following::ProductId)])"/>
{
 "StoreId": <xsl:value-of select="ProductResult/StoreId"/>,
 "Locations": [
 <xsl:for-each select="//ProductId[not(. = following::ProductId)]">
   <xsl:sort select="."/>
  {
  "ProductId": "<xsl:value-of select="."/>,
  "Locations": [
  <xsl:call-template name="location">
       <xsl:with-param name="productId" select="."/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  ]
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; $uniqueProducts">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
]}
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template  name="location">
<xsl:param name="productId"/>
<xsl:for-each select="//ProductResult[ProductId=$productId]">
{
"Location": "<xsl:value-of select="Location"/>",
"ModuleNumber": "<xsl:value-of select="ModuleNumber"/>"
    }
   <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the following (corrected, as you didn't close the `StoreId` in your example)
**Input XML:**

```
<ProductResults>    
  <ProductResult>                       
     <ProductId>1000</ProductId>
     <Location>Bangalore</Location>
     <ModuleNumber>02</ModuleNumber>
     <StoreId>1234</StoreId>                
  </ProductResult>
  <ProductResult>           
     <ProductId>2000</ProductId>
     <ModuleNumber>03</ModuleNumber>
     <Location>Bangalore</Location>
     <StoreId>1234</StoreId>     
  </ProductResult>
  <ProductResult>   
     <ProductId>1000</ProductId>
     <ModuleNumber>01</ModuleNumber>
     <Location>Mumbai</Location>
     <StoreId>1234</StoreId>    
  </ProductResult>
  <ProductResult>       
     <ProductId>4000</ProductId>
     <ModuleNumber>02</ModuleNumber>
     <Location>Kolkata</Location>
     <StoreId>1234</StoreId>    
  </ProductResult>
  <ProductResult>       
     <ProductId>1000</ProductId>
     <ModuleNumber>03</ModuleNumber>
     <Location>Chennai</Location>
     <StoreId>1234</StoreId>    
  </ProductResult>
</ProductResults>
```

produces the following
**Output XML:**

```
{
"StoreId": 1234,
"Locations": [

{
  "ProductId": "1000,
  "Locations": [

{
"Location": "Bangalore",
"ModuleNumber": "02"
    }
   ,
{
"Location": "Mumbai",
"ModuleNumber": "01"
    }
   ,
{
"Location": "Chennai",
"ModuleNumber": "03"
    }
  ]
  ,
{
  "ProductId": "2000,
  "Locations": [

{
"Location": "Bangalore",
"ModuleNumber": "03"
    }
  ]
  ,
 {
  "ProductId": "4000,
  "Locations": [

 {
  "Location": "Kolkata",
  "ModuleNumber": "02"
    }
  ] 
]}
```

Note that this is only an example for the grouping, with e.g. an additional for-each loop it would be possible to adjust this to take care for more than a single StoreId.
For simplification I've just wrote this for the one `StoreId` provided using `<xsl:value-of select="ProductResult/StoreId"/>` instead of checking for different `StoreId` values and processing all of them.

For detailed references you can check this article by Jeni Tennison http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml for Muenchian Grouping, and 
you can e.g. have a look at http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4486.html for XSLT Grouping.

**Update**: Just adjusted first posted XSLT, and for explanation how this works - the `<xsl:for-each select="//ProductId[not(. = following::ProductId)]">` loop processes all unique `ProductId` values, calling the `<xsl:template name="location">` with the current `ProductId` as parameter and generating the output for every location that matches the `ProductId`. Though the updated approach doesn't use Muenchian Grouping, it may still be of value for you so I'll keep the reference.

Comment: Hi matt, thank you very much for the quick response. I tried applying the above logic but while loading the XSLT file for the transformation, I am getting an error saying 'Name cannot begin with the '.' character, hexadecimal value 0x2E'. I did some research on this issue. Few says it's encoding issue but I tried introducing UTF-16 in XSLT file but didn't work out for me. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: @user3796454 I've just checked the issue and think I've fixed it - see updated XSLT in answer. While I adjusted the first version to the current, I've accidentally adjusted `<xsl:with-param name="productId" select="."/>` to `<xsl:with-param name="."/>` which caused the error. Should work now, saved a demo here: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsU/4